# When I click into another link, only the header shows

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I imported php files in wordpress and my linking into another page is not working properly. When I click into another page some of them show only the header but the content is not there. Also, sometimes it only displays white.

How can I fix this, so that the content is always shown correctly?

Comment: Try with Permalinks ON OFF in settings -> permalinks

Comment: Also can you post site url?

Comment: There must be something messed with PHP function or PHP open or close tags. Check your code or paste your code.

Comment: Add you code here.  @cwang-basiwang